# "Sorry, I didn’t find a group or device named _____" with Custom Skill

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

I'm in the process of creating an Alexa Skill to allow me to control my garage doors (which are not supported by Alexa directly). All of my backend triggering code works, it's the interaction from Alexa is where I am struggling as Alexa seems to prefer to treat the words "garage door" as belonging to a device group, despite it also being the invocation name for this skill.

I've created my intent and given it sample utterances such as:

- open garage door one
- close garage door one
- open garage door two
- close garage door two
- open garage door
- close garage door

I've even added a couple with the intent slots for the device state (open or closed as defined by a custom slot type) and the door number (AMAZON.NUMBER).

Only one of the above utterances will actually trigger my skill though, "open garage door", the rest will get a response of "Sorry, I didn't find a group or device named garage door two".

Short of changing to a less intuitive model of "hide car number two", I'm struggling to see what I'm missing here. Any ideas what I might be doing wrong? I should note that I am saving & rebuilding my model every time between changes & testing.

It's silly that it seems it'd be easier to use a controllable light switch, name it garage door, and attach to it something which triggers my code.

Answer (score 1):

What is the actual utterance you speak to Alexa? It sounds like you were trying to invoke the sample utterance directly without opening the skill first.

Assuming you want to invoke your skill + intent with an one-line command, Alexa expects the utterance in this format:

```
Alexa, <invocation phase> <skill invocation name> <connecting word> <sample utterance>
```

- invocation phase -- ask, tell, open, use...etc.
- skill invocation name -- that's defined by you in your skill
- connecting word -- and, by, from, in, using, with...etc.
- sample utterance -- that's defined by you in your skill

Based on your skill invocation name `garage door` and sample utterances above, the actual command to Alexa would be something like, "*Alexa, open **garage door** and **open garage door one***", which I don't think is what you wanted.

Instead, I would change the sample utterance to something like "open door one", and the actual command to Alexa would be "*Alexa, tell **garage door** to **open door one***", which is shorter and more natural.

---

> Only one of the above utterances will actually trigger my skill though, "open garage door"

"*Alexa, open garage door*" launches your skill without a specific request (no intent). Your skill should receive a `LaunchRequest` which then you can prompt for the next step. A multi-turn interaction should look like this:

1. user: "*Alexa, open garage door*"
2. Alexa send a `LaunchRequest` to your skill
3. Your skill prompt the user for the next action, while keeping the skill session open
4. user: "open door one"
5. Alexa send the corresponding intent to your skill

https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/custom-skills/understanding-how-users-invoke-custom-skills.html